# SQL Connection Pool Exceding limit despite Finally blocks closing the connection

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

I've been over this site up and down but I cannot find whats going on with my WebService Connection Pool. Using an application, I call a WebMethod on my service which in turn fires the code below.

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
   Try
       Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
           cmd.Connection = cn
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
           cmd.CommandText = "select * " &
                        " from Customer " &
                        " where CustomerID=@CustomerID and active=1"
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
           cmd.Parameters("@CustomerID").Value = CustomerID
       End Using
       da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       da.Fill(ds, "Customer")
   Catch ex As Exception
       Throw ex
   Finally
       If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
       End If
   End Try
End Using
```

Then within my SSMS I fire the below and I can see on my DB I still have an Active connection with a 'sleeping' status

```
SELECT 
   DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
   COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
   loginame as LoginName,
   status
FROM
   sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
   dbid = 16  'my dbid
GROUP BY 
   dbid, loginame, status
```

I pass over similar methods and my NumberOfConnections just keeps building. help

```
DBNAME | NumberOfConnections | LoginName | Status
MyDB   | 1                   | jgritten  | sleeping
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no locks?

Comment: There is no point to your exception handler. The Finally block is useless because the connection can't be open at that point and, even if it is, it would be closed at the `End Using` statement.  Also, your exception handler is worse than no handler at all because you're using `Throw ex`.  By doing so, you lose all the call stack information and make your method the source of the exception.  If you ever need to rethrow an exception, which you don't here, then you should just use `Throw` alone.

Comment: the Handler was there because i read somewhere if an error was occurring during the Adapter portion it could be skipping the close

Comment: @Zaggler can you elaborate? What kind of locks are you thinking could be happening? The life of the connection is supposed to be contained within the statement you see above. Created during the Using, then closed after the .Fill() and terminated on the End Using.

Answer (score -1):

You may have simply lost it in translating the code for your post -- but there is no cn.Open(). I would also cn.Close() in the Try statement and then just as a catch-all leave the close in the finally statement. You may also include the check and cn.close() in the catch statement so that any exception will also close the connection.

Secondly, your using statement for sqlcommand ends before you fill your dataadapter with it.. Fix those things and terminate existing connections. Verify your closing connections in your transactions. Maybe step through and make sure it's not secretly throwing exceptions or write the exception string out to the Console just in case it's skipping on by.

Comment: There's no need to call `Open` on a connection when calling `Fill` or `Update` on a data adapter because they will implicitly open the connection. They will also implicitly close the connection if they open it, so there's no need to call `Close` at all. The fact that the connection object is created with a `Using` statement also means that there's no need to close it, because it will be implicitly disposed and that closes it. If you are going to use a `Try...Catch` block though, it is correct to close the connection in the `Finally` block and ONLY there.

Comment: Just to qualify, it's appropriate to call `Open` explicitly if you're making multiple `Fill` or `Update` calls in order to avoid opening and closing the connection multiple times.  If it's just one call though, it's appropriate to let the opening and closing to be done implicitly.

Comment: Ah, well you may be right but both of your comments totally skip over the second fact which I brought up. The SQLCommand does not exist in that context at all. That line would throw an exception into the catch block which is still unhandled since that just throws another exception likely kicking it totally out of the trycatchfinally block entirely. Let me know your thoughts.